# Shortcode not getting replaced

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I used this to obtain my post:

```
$the_slug = 'kontakt';
$args=array(
    'name'           => $the_slug,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'suppress_filters' => false
);
$my_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

The resulting post is:

[image]

but the text still contains the plugins shortcode

`[wpgmza id="1"]`

I used the plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-maps

Am I using a way of parsing for the post that somehow stops the plugin from working?

Should I not use the text editor to add the shortcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortcodes get replaced when you output the content via `the_content()` function, or apply the filters hooked to `the_content`. If you look at raw post data, you will always see the original shortcode placeholder, that is normal and expected.

Comment: thanks for the hint. The solution is btw

            `<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $my_posts[0]->post_content); ?>`